# Pointer arithmetic getting wrong output

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

In the following program, Here `ptr` Has been declared as a pointer to an integer pointer and assigned the base address of the array `p[]`, which has been declared as an array of integer pointer. Suppose `ptr` contains the address `9016` (suppose the starting address of p is 9016) before `ptr` is incremented and after `ptr++`, it will contain the value 9020 (suppose int takes 4 bytes).

So `ptr-p` should give the output as 4 i.e (9020-9016=4). But it is giving output as 1 . why?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    static int a[]={0,1,2,3,4};
    static int *p[]={a,a+1,a+2,a+3,a+4};
    int **ptr=p;
    ptr++;
    printf("%d",ptr-p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cast the pointers to an integer type individually, and only then subtract.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The result of one pointer minus another pointer is the number of **elements** between them, not the number of bytes.

```
int **ptr=p;
ptr++;
```

`ptr` moves forward one element, so `ptr - p` has a value of `1`.

BTW, this behavior is consistent with `ptr++` (which means `ptr = p + 1;` in your example.

Comment: Thanks @yu Hao thanki

Answer (score 2):

Subtraction of a pointer from another pointer of same base type returns an integer,which denotes the number of element of that between the two pointers.

If we have 2 pointer two `int` pointers `p1` and `p2`, containing addresses 1000 and 1016 respectively, then `p2-p1` will give `4` (since size of `int` 4).

Answer (score 1):

When you find the difference between two pointer you will get the number of objects between them.
In this case as the objects are of type integer you correctly got the value 1.

If you want to know the value in terms of bytes then you should do:

```
printf("%d",(char *)ptr-(char *)p);
```

It will print 4.